# styling a node having some defined text without using javascript

Tags: html, css

I have a node in my html which is as below

```
<h2> My Text </h2>
```

Is there any way to style h2 element on the basis of its Text(**without using any class**)

eg.

```
h2[text='My Text']{
color:red;
}
```

Please note that I don't want to use javascript code

Comment: if you don't want to use Javascript, so it may be depend on server side scripting such as PHP for example.

Comment: No you can't. Can you add other attributes (`data-*` or `style` for example) or do you know its position (any characteristic) in HTML code (mainly "it always has a certain parent/ancestor and it's the only one" or even "the only one *not* to have a class")?

Answer (score 1):

no, you can't do it with just css. there was a proposal for a `contains` selector but it wasn't realized. currently javascript is the only way.

If you can attach some identifier like a class to the element you can style it normally, but to answer your questions, no you can't select a element in css by it's content

Answer (score 0):

Html5

```
<h2 class="YourClass"> My text </h2>
```

Css

```
.YourClass {
  color:red
}
```

For what i understood is that you want to style h2. I dont know why do you want to use javascript instead of css3.

Can you show us the div which the h2 is in? You can use a path selector.

```
<div>
 <nav>
   <h2>My Text</h2>
 </nav>
<div>

div nav h2 {
  color:red
}
```

Comment: I dont have to use any class

Comment: this isnt what the OP asked.

Comment: so you want to style h2 without having a class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't any way of doing this using just css. You can of course do this with javascript but since it's not an option for you then I suggest creating and adding classes according to the text will somewhat closer to what you expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first line nth selector -

```
h2::first-line {
        color: red;
}
```

More info on nth selectors here - https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Comment: It will not solve my problem as it will not check  "inner text". it will add color to first line of every header inrespective of its text

Comment: How does this solve the problem posed?

Comment: Would need to use JavaScript in that case to pick inner text